# Elastsearch query causing NodeJS heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, memory-leaks

**What's happen now?**

Recenly I build a Elasticsearch query. The main function is to get data count per hours until 12 weeks ago.

When the query get call over and over again. NodeJS memory will start from 20mb growing to 1024mb. **And surprisingly the memory aren’t immediately get to the top.** Its more like stably under 25mb ( maintain about several minutes ) and suddenly start to growing like (25mb,46mb,125mb,350mb...until 1024mb) and finally causing NodeJS memory leak. **Whatever I call this query or not, The memory will still growing up and won’t release at all. And this scenario only happen at remote server (running in docker)**, At local docker env is totally fine (the memory is identical).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6pve.png)

**How am I query?**

like below.

```
const query = {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { terms: { '_id.keyword': array_id } },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date_created": {
                            "gte": start_timestamp - timestamp_twelve_weeks,
                            "lt": start_timestamp
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "shortcode_log": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "date_created",
                "interval": "3600ms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What's the return value?**

like below ( total query time is around 2 sec ) .

```
{
    "aggs_res": {
        "shortcode_log": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1594710000,
                    "doc_count": 2268
                },
                {
                    "key": 1594713600,
                    "doc_count": 3602
                },
                {//.....total item count 2016
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, In my view the memory leak is not because of your elasticsearch query. elasticsearch is an external module for your code and cannot cause a memory leak. I think It would be better for you to commit request part of your code and just set a single response as simulations of the response. In that case you will understand that this is because of elasticsearch or not. please check your variables to become free after getting out of that scope. I am kind of sure that this problem is just because of your code not from elasticsearch and your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New update. The issue is solved. The problem in project has **a layer between server and DB**. So the code of this layer causing the query memory can't release.

Answer (score 0):

If your histogram interval is really of 3600ms(it should not be 3600s ?), it's a really short period of time to do the aggregation on 12 weeks.
It means 0.06 minutes.
24000 periods per day
168000 per week
2016000 for 12 weeks.
It can explain

1. Why your script wait for a long before doing anything
2. Why your memory explode when you try to loop on the buckets

In your example, you have 2016 buckets back only.
I think that their is a small difference between your 2 tests.